# When to use Event Properties in C# objects and when use just events

Tags: c#, events

Would like to know the use-case wherein it is appropriate to use Event Properties instead of just Events and vice versa.

Comment: What are event properties?

Comment: please refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8843a9ch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You mean auto-implemented vs. manually implemented events?

Comment: Looking from the Implementation point of view where it is appropriate to use Event Properties and where it is not .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, obviously, event properties can be used to override the default behavior for adding/removing event handlers. For example if you want to make sure there's ever only one handler at a time, etc.

So my answer is: Unless there's something you don't like about the way event handlers are added/removed by default, keep your hands off event properties. If you have to do anything different from the defaults you'll have to implement event properties.

Personal opinion: In all the years I've been using C#/.NET now I have not once felt the need to add an event property...

Comment: You also have to use the manually implemented event if you're implementing it explicitly from an interface.  That's about the only situation I've used them in production code.